# What's the correct location to install a bunch of scripts & support files for a program?

Tags: shell-script, directory-structure

I have a project that comprises a bunch of different files (listed below). I'm creating an install script for it, and want to make sure they all go in the right place from a unix hierarchy perspective.

- There's the main script that does most of the lifting work.
- There's a script that starts a particular kernel module in the right way.

  - [Both the above scripts are started at boot by .service files in systemd]
- There's a couple of filesystems (just .bin files) that are used by the kernel module mentioned above
- There needs to be a write-accessible (to the main script at least) directory to keep files that are currently being run by the program. This isn't temporary and needs to persist after boot.

I asked on twitter and received options ranging from /opt/pishift, to /usr/local/share, to ~/.pishift/, to /usr/local/bin, to ~/pishift or /etc/pishift.

The main script will not need to be run by the user, as it'll be started on boot by systemd - so I think that means I shouldn't put it in /usr/local/bin, as then it'd be in their path.

If you're looking for more context regarding the question, the project is here: https://github.com/tomhartley/pishift

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to try to find where your sofware fits in [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). Being run by systemd makes me think that the best place is /opt.